# What countries voted for letting Saudi Arabia join the UN women's rights commission?

Tags: united-nations, civil-rights, saudi-arabia

What countries voted for letting Saudi Arabia join the women rights commission? It [happened](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/saudi-arabia-un-womens-right-commission-un-watch-middle-east-muslim-driving-clothes-a7698536.html) so I would like to know what countries voted to make this possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the United Nations [press release](https://www.un.org/press/en/2017/ecosoc6824.doc.htm), the election was conducted using a secret ballot. In a secret ballot, there is no way to know who voted for a particular candidate.

To help you out a *little*, not every nation was capable of voting. The UN [org chart](https://www.un.org/en/aboutun/structure/pdfs/UN_System_Chart_30June2015.pdf) shows that the Commission on the Status of Women is organized by the Economic and Social Council. You can find a list of current council members [here](https://www.un.org/ecosoc/en/content/members). The voters must be on that list.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Commission_on_the_Status_of_Women) claims that geographic distribution is an important criteria for election, requiring:

> thirteen members from Africa; eleven from Asia; nine from Latin America and Caribbean; eight from Western Europe and other States and four from Eastern Europe.

This is unsourced on wikipedia, and I haven't found the documents outlining how these elections are conducting it - so take all that with a healthy amount of skepticism. However, if it's true it helps explain the somewhat unusual choices in Commission members.

Comment: Notice how most of the countries on the council are "friendly" with KSA for one reason or another e.g. Religion, Money, oil, Weapons exports, Strategic alliance against another nation etc. Hardly surprising that they voted KSA in. +1

Comment: Your Wikipedia link is broken; I think you pasted in the quote instead of the URL by mistake.

Comment: I can't find the document for the ESC, but I can attest that all elections of this form are conducted in geographic voting blocs.

Comment: @Benjamin It would be really nice if you could find the document. It would greatly reduce the number of countries who voted for Saudi Arabia.

Comment: It makes sense to vote in a country aspirationally so they can reform.

Comment: @Trilarion I am sorry that I wasn't clear, I mean amongst the candidates. All eligible nations vote, but they vote on candidates organized by geography.

Comment: @Benjamin - I agree. Since I couldn't find the documentation, I left it as wiki-speculation.